# Minimum system requirements for a thin-client PC?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, memory, terminal, cpu

How much RAM, CPU, Disk does a thin-client need in order for it to work on a terminal server like Ubuntu or Windows XP? (Network Boot).

Comment: Are you going to go for purpose built thin clients, or re-purposing spare hardware?

Comment: It will be all brand new hardware.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Ok I realized I'll probably have a hard time finding low-end parts that are brand new since most of what's being sold is for standalone desktops and it's probably overkill for thin-clients.

Comment: Actually nearly any SBC would do. On the other hand, some of these think clients seem impressively cheap

Comment: I think this classifies as off topic... The minimum system requirements for Ubuntu and WinXP are published on both of their respective websites.  You could also look @ the requirements for a given thin client, and go from there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can change, mainly depending on whether you need GUI and whether you need local storage. You can use Etherboot, PXE, or other kind of remote boot to reduce or eliminate the need of local storage.

It also depend on your selection of software for the thin client which in turn depends on the server software and user needs.

If you'll take [Thinstation](http://www.thinstation.org/) OS for example, here is a quote from their site:

"Thinstation runs on ordinary PC hardware (32/64 bit i686 class). You may either reuse older computers or save a lot of time on workstation administration. Or both! An old Pentium-II with 128 MB RAM or better can be a perfectly useful workstation. And you don't need a hard disk - you can boot off the network and even have a silent workstation. Workstation devices (floppy/HD/CD/USB) and printers (LPT/USB) are supported. "

Answer (score 0):

A quick, rather unscientific look at actual thin clients (well whatever's on deal extreme) and the [thin client forum](http://www.thinclientforum.com/) seem to indicate that most of them seem to have between 128 mb to 256 mb of ram, and often low powered arm chips (say 800 mhz processors), or somewhat exotic slow x86 class processors.

Any off the shelf Single Board system (say the raspberry pi or beagleboard) will likely do what you need to run a thin client.